# select exclude rows with same key using postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

video_real

```
 device_id | video_definition 

         1 |              360
         1 |              480
(2 rows)
```

video_all

```
 device_id | video_definition 

         1 |              360
         1 |              480
         1 |              540
         1 |              720
         1 |             1080
```

I want to return

```
device_id | video_definition 

         1 |              540
         1 |              720
         1 |             1080
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Except. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the definition of an "anti-join". You can do:

```sql
select a.*
from video_all a
left join video_real r on r.device_id = a.device_id
                      and r.video_definition = a.video_definition
where r.device_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXCEPT` operator. This compares the results from both queries and removes any matching values.

A more thorough explanation can be found [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-except/).

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE video_real (
  "device_id" INTEGER,
  "video_definition" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO video_real
  ("device_id", "video_definition")
VALUES
  ('1', '360'),
  ('1', '480');

CREATE TABLE video_all (
  "device_id" INTEGER,
  "video_definition" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO video_all
  ("device_id", "video_definition")
VALUES
  ('1', '360'),
  ('1', '480'),
  ('1', '540'),
  ('1', '720'),
  ('1', '1080');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.device_id, a.video_definition FROM video_all a
EXCEPT
SELECT b.device_id, b.video_definition FROM video_real b;
```

| device_id | video_definition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1080 |
| 1 | 720 |
| 1 | 540 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)